# simple integration by substitution(region change)

Tags: integration

$$ t=\frac{y}{\theta}$$

$$\int _{0}^{\theta} \frac{ny}{\theta}(1-\frac{y}{\theta})^{n-1}dy = \int_{0}^{1} n\theta t(1-t)^{n-1} dt $$

Q1. Why region change from (0,theta) to (0,1)?

Q2. Why $\frac{ny}{\theta}$ is $n\theta t$? shouldn't be $nt$?

Consider that I'm beginner for this integral.Please explain with specific example. and denote one by one. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: If $y\in[0,\theta]$, then $t=\frac y\theta\in[0,1]$.

Q2: Indeed, $\frac{ny}\theta=nt$. The extra $\theta$ is from $\mathrm{d}y=\theta\,\mathrm{d}t$